# React Rendering Different components based on hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component that is supposed to switch between the login view, and the Register view based on a hook state. React keeps passing the error: "Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `boolean` type." even though I have worked on other components before the same way. Any help would be appreciated

```
const UserPane = () => {
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState(false)
  const toggleNewUser = () => setNewUser(!newUser)

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container p-5 pb-2 mb-3">
        {newUser ?
          <Register /> :
          <Login />
        }
        {newUser.toString()}
        <a onClick={() => setNewUser(!newUser)} style={{ color: "#845ec2", cursor: "pointer" }} onClick>
          Don't have an account? Click here to register
        </a>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing error because of the last onClick (scroll to end of the line)

```
<a onClick={() => setNewUser(!newUser)} style={{ color: "#845ec2", cursor: "pointer" }} onClick> //<---This
```

This last onClick essentially overwrites the previous onClick with `onClick={true}` which is not an acceptable onClick value

Comment: Thank you! Dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you are facing an issue with toggling the `newUser`.

To alter the state, you should use

```js
setNewUser(prev => !prev)
```